# How to change server maximum execution time

Tags: php

Just to learn, I've created an unlimited loop function which is like below:

```
    <?php
for ($t=1; $t>0; $t++){
echo ">> Its Running...<br/>"   ;
}
?>
```

I'm on shared host and Apache Server. When I run this on host, then it shows "Maximum Execution Time 30 second exceeded." Then I tried to use the below line

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "0"); /// for unlimited exe. time
```

It is still showing ""Maximum Execution Time 30 second exceeded in Line 4."
why the ini setting not changed. may there any option in my shared host owner side to block changing ini setting.
-I'm a learner and eager to know more and more on PHP. any help is appreciated.

(Actually I'm creating a MLM project where I need to run some cron job which take 10-15 minute)

Comment: hopefully, you have a way to kill the process manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hosting provider can prevent you from changing the setting. That is probably what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

You could give [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)() a try.

Answer (score 0):

Php by default have the time limit for code execution so to avoid that you will have to extend the timer to do so 
place the set_time_limit(0) in the for loop

```
<?php
for ($t=1; $t>0; $t++){
set_time_limit(0)
echo ">> Its Running...<br/>"   ;
}
?>
```

for more details
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php